# Passing variables to dynamic exception messages for translator to use in twig templates

Tags: twig, symfony

In a symfony application, how do I pass variable(s) `$dynamicPart = 'I always change!';` to `throw new NotFoundException('error.static.dynamic');` in order to get message below?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "error.static.dynamic",
    "message": "Dynamic message is invalid - "I always change!"."
  }
}
```

The static version works fine because it is always the same so this `throw new NotFoundException('error.static.invalid');` will successfuly output:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "error.static.invalid",
    "message": "Static message is invalid."
  }
}
```

**CURRENT CODE**

**messages.en.yml**

```
error:
    static:
        invalid: Static message is invalid.

    dynamic:
        invalid: Dynamic message is invalid - "%dynamicPart%".
```

**exception.json.twig**

```
{
  {
    {
      'error': {
        'code': exception.message,
        'message': exception.message|trans
      }
    }|json_encode|raw
  }
}
```

If I use:

```
throw new NotFoundException(
    $this->translator->trans(
        'error.static.dynamic',
        ['%dynamicPart%' => 'I always change!']
    )
);
```

then I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Dynamic message is invalid - "I always change!".",
    "message": "Dynamic message is invalid - "I always change!"."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your twig:

```
{
  {
    {
      'error': {
        'code': exception.message,
        'message': 'error.dynamic.invalid'|trans({"%dynamicPart%": dynamicPartValue})
      }
    }|json_encode|raw
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll let you know once I check it but blocked by something else now. Thank you.

Comment: Just checked your answer again. I'm trying to get the key (`error.dynamic.invalid`) via the message. You should assume that you never know `error.dynamic.invalid`.

Comment: I built my answer using the key of your messages.en.yml file. I'm actually a bit confused since you show 3 different keys : error.dynamic.invalid, exception.message and error.static.dynamic